# How to send multiple keystrokes fast in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, key, midi, keystroke, piano

So I've been working on a script that takes MIDI files and plays them automatically on [Virtual Piano](https://virtualpiano.net). However the main issue I'm running into is sending the keystrokes, I've managed to be able to use [RobotJS](https://robotjs.io/docs/syntax) to send keystrokes one at a time but this becomes an issue for sharp keys and chords. To send a sharp key you can't just send an uppercase letter you have to send a lowercase letter with the modifier `shift`. You also can only send one at a time so the end result is me doing a loop of all the keys in the chord and it having like a fast sweep left to right of the keys instead of chords all pressed at the same time, and it sounds horrific. I also tried [Node Key Sender](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-key-sender) but I quickly got rid of that as it spawns thousands of java processes and crashes my PC.

Does anyone have any suggestions or know a better way of going about this?

Comment: Have you considered just triggering the virtual piano within a browser extension?

Answer (score 0):

[When using the modifiers (alt, shift, ctrl) with robotjs](http://robotjs.io/docs/syntax#keytapkey-modifier), instead of tapping with the modifier:

```
robot.keyTap("a","shift")
```

Toggle the modifier, tap your desired key, and then untoggle the modifier.

```
const play = (key, mod) => {
    if (mod) { 
        robot.keyToggle(mod, "down")
        robot.keyTap(key)
        robot.keyToggle(mod, "up")
    } else {
        robot.keyTap(key)
    }
}
```